# Is there a way to chunk/split up a redirected file into several files?

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a sensor that sends data via UDP. I use netcat and use a redirect to write the data to a file.  The specific command that I use is `nc -ul 7954 > data.dat` to save all of the incoming data into a file.  I'd like to come up with some way to "chunk" (aka: split) the data after 10 MB so that no file is larger than a size limit.

The OS is a stripped Ubuntu Linux, and uname -a gives: `Linux ZeroPi 4.14.111 #189 SMP Fri Apr 23 17:07:22 CST 2021 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux`

Is there a method to chunk/split up a redirected file via the command line?

Comment: I may be able to help but I'm not a native English speaker and I'm not sure what you mean by "chunk" or "chunk up". Can you rephrase? Do you want something like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/644659/108618) maybe?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I tried to edit the question accordingly.  yeah, chunk means to cut up into several groups from one original.  I'll check that link.

Comment: If you have GNU `split`, maybe `nc -ul 7954 | split -b 10M -d - data.dat`. See `man split` for more options. With POSIX `split` you have to use alphabetic suffixes instead of numeric ones.

Comment: OK, now it seems to me you want to split the file. Questions: (1) What is your OS? (2) Do you need to work with already existing `data.dat` without stopping the `nc` already running? or can we start over and pipe to `split`?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it's not existing, it's like what Bodo said.  I'll see if that works for me.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski it's some stripped Ubuntu Linux `Linux ZeroPi 4.14.111 #189 SMP Fri Apr 23 17:07:22 CST 2021 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux`

Comment: How long will this command be running? You might need a mechanism that deletes old files. What do you plan to do with the resulting files? Is it only some sort of log like? If a program will process the data you have to think about how the program will detect when a new file has been started. Please [edit] your question to add requested information, don't use comments to answer.

Comment: @Bodo Your split comment worked.  Can you please make it an answer so that I might accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have GNU split you can use something like

```
nc -ul 7954 | split -b 10M -d - data.dat.
```

See man split for more options.

With POSIX split you would have to use alphabetic suffixes instead of numeric ones.

---

At the time of this answer, the question does not tell how long or for how much data the command will run or how the resulting files will be used. This simple solution might not be sufficient if the pipeline is expected to run for a long time.

Possible problems that may require additional thoughts:

- Terminated processes might need to be restarted.
- Handle file switching in a program that processes the data.
- Remove old output files if the number or total size exceeds a limit.
- The numeric suffix generated by `split` might overflow or wrap around when it reaches a certain limit.